# Python library for dynamic documents

Tags: python, markdown, r-markdown

I want to write a script that generates reports for each team in my unit where each report uses the same template, but where the numbers specific to each team is used for each report. The report should be in a format like .pdf that non-programmers know how to open and read. This is in many ways similar to rmarkdown for R, but the reports I want to generate are based on data from code already written in python.

The solution I am looking for does not need to export directly to pdf. It can export to markdown and then I know how to convert. I do not need any fancier formatting than what markdown provides. It does not need to be markdown, but I know how to do everything else in markdown, if I only find a way to dynamically populate numbers and text in a markdown template from python code.

What I need is something that is similar to the code block below, but on a bigger scale and instead of printing output on screen this would saved to a file (.md or .pdf) that can then be shared with each team.

```
user = {'name':'John Doe', 'email':'jd@example.com'}
print('Name is {}, and email is {}'.format(user["name"], user["email"]))
```

So the desired functionality heavily influenced by my previous experience using rmarkdown would look something like the code block below, where the the template is a string or a file read as a string, with placeholders that will be populated from variables (or Dicts or objects) from the python code. Then the output can be saved and shared with the teams.

```py
user = {'name':'John Doe', 'email':'jd@example.com'}
template = 'Name is `user["name"]`, and email is `user["email"]`'
output = render(template, user)
```

When trying to find a rmarkdown equivalent in python, I have found a lot of pointers to Jupyter Notebook which I am familiar with, and very much like, but it is not what I am looking for, as the point is not to share the code, only a rendered output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question was up-voted I want to answer my own question, as I found a solution that was perfect for me. In the end I shared these reports in a repo, so I write the reports in markdown and do not convert them to PDF. The reason I still think this is an answer to my original quesiton is that this works similar to creating markdown in Rmarkdown which was the core of my question, and markdown can easily be converted to PDF.

I solved this by using a library for backend generated HTML pages. I happened to use `jinja2` but there are many other options.

First you need a template file in markdown. Let say this is `template.md`:

```md
## Overview
**Name:** {{repo.name}}<br>
**URL:** {{repo.url}}

| Branch name | Days since last edit |
|---|---|
{% for branch in repo.branches %}
|{{branch[0]]}}|{{branch[1]}}|
{% endfor %}
```

And then you have use this in your python script:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import codecs

#create an dict will all data that will be populate the template
repo = {}
repo.name = 'training-kit'
repo.url = 'https://github.com/github/training-kit'
repo.branches = [
    ['master',15],
    ['dev',2]
]

#render the template
with open('template.md', 'r') as file:
  template = Template(file.read(),trim_blocks=True)
rendered_file = template.render(repo=repo)

#output the file
output_file = codecs.open("report.md", "w", "utf-8")
output_file.write(rendered_file)
output_file.close()
```

If you are OK with your dynamic doc being in markdown you are done and the report is written to `report.py`. If you want PDF you can use pandoc to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to install and use the pyFPDF Library, that enables you to write and export PDF files directly from python. The Library was ported from php and offers the same functionality as it's php-variant.

1.) Clone and install pyFPDF

Git-Bash:

```
    git clone https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf.git
    cd pyfpdf
    python setup.py install
```

2.) After successfull installation, you can use python code similar as if you'd work with fpdf in php like:

```
    from fpdf import FPDF

    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
    pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
    pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt="Hello", border=0)
    pdf.output('myTest.pdf', 'F')
```

For more Information, take a look at: 
https://pypi.org/project/fpdf/

To work with pyFPDF clone repo from: https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf

pyFPDF Documentation:
https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html